# WYSIWG with jsFiddle-like features

Tags: html, forms, webforms, wysiwyg

I am looking for a collaboration tool that would allow our end users to design their own html forms to include with their project specs to make things easier for the developers. Since all of these people are non-coders, I'm looking for something with a WSIWYG, so that they can interactively design the forms then share them with us via a link or sharing tool. They won't need to do any JS or CSS, just visual design. Does something like this exist or do I need to create something myself? I've been looking for a while, to no avail.

Comment: If all they need to do is visual design, what features from jsFiddle would they need? It kind of sounds like they just need a graphics editor.

Comment: the only features i would want from jsFiddle would be the sharing features really.